# call sh script from KornShell

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, sh, ksh

I have to write a KornShell (ksh) script to call Bourne scripts (sh) in another directory which then it calls the java program.  I have the sh script working but not sure how to call it from ksh.

Can anyone tell me how to call (reference) the sh script in ksh script?  I also need to pass in parameters to sh.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
/bin/sh /other-directory/shellscript.sh
```

Comment: Alternatively, make sure the first line in `/other-directory/shellscript.sh` is `#!/bin/sh` and that it has execute permission set, then you can call it without the `/bin/sh` prefix.